# Manually create Latex Regression Table from R

Tags: r, latex, regression

I have a regression table that I want to export to Latex. But the object I'm working with does not support any traditional package like 'stargazer', or 'texreg'. I have to build it manually. This are the results:

```
                   Estimate   Std. Error    z value
(Intercept):1 -4.652887e-01 3.149742e-01  -1.477228
x1            -3.277175e-05 1.014935e-05  -3.228952
x2            -2.446376e-05 6.717509e-06  -3.641790
x3             1.666235e+00 5.228731e-01   3.186691
x4             2.507294e-08 5.276769e-09   4.751570
```

What I want is:

```
(Intercept)   -4.652887e-01 
              (3.149742e-01)
x1            -3.277175e-05 
              (1.014935e-05)
x2            -2.446376e-05 
              (6.717509e-06)
x3             1.666235e+00
              (5.228731e-01)
x4             2.507294e-08
              (5.276769e-09)
```

I could do this manually (see below), but I was looking for something more dynamic that I could apply in several contexts.

```
res <- matrix(NA, nrow=2*dim(ctable), ncol=1)

res[1,] <- ctable[1,1]
res[3,] <- ctable[2,1]
res[5,] <- ctable[3,1]
res[7,] <- ctable[4,1]
res[9,] <- ctable[5,1]

res[2,] <- ctable[1,2]
res[4,] <- ctable[2,2]
res[6,] <- ctable[3,2]
res[8,] <- ctable[4,2]
res[10,] <- ctable[5,2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `xtable`?  The xtable gallery (google it) shows similar examples, but w/o data I can't test myself.

Comment: What kind of object is it? You can either write an extension for ``texreg`` (see section 6 of this document: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v55/i08/) or use the ``createTexreg()`` function to hand over the estimates, standard errors etc. and then apply ``texreg()``, ``screenreg()`` or ``htmlreg()`` to the resulting object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I understood well your problem. But if you want just create your table dynamically, you can use the function below.

```
create_table = function(table_)
{
    p_table = data.frame(Variables=NA, Values=NA)
    for(i in 1:dim(table_)[1])
    {
        est_error = table_[i,1:2] # Im assuming that you know that 2 first columns are the values that you want
        name = c(rownames(table_)[i], '') # The final table rownames
        name_values = cbind(Variables=name, Values=est_error)
        p_table = rbind(p_table, name_values)
    }
    rownames(p_table) = 1:dim(p_table)[1]
    return(na.omit(p_table))
}
```

And you can use this function in the following way. Below, one example using the mtcars dataset.

```
ctable = summary(lm(mpg~. , data = mtcars))$coefficients
output_table = create_table(ctable)
```

The output is something like you posted. Then, is easy create a tex table from a R dataframe using the xtable package.

```
xtable::xtable(output_table)
```

Comment: This is awesome, Djongs! Can you help me having the parenthesis between the numbers in the rows 2,4,6,8, and 10?

Comment: Yes, you can use the paste or sprintf command to create dynamically it. For example, paste("(", "string", ")").

Comment: how could you put to the standard errors parenthesis and add stars if from the input you have the p-value?